# Opening the connection using okhttp

Tags: android, httpconnection, okhttp, okio

I'm trying to Open the connection using okhttp.

something like,

```
urlConnection = client.open(url);
```

**does not work with the new ok-http.jar file**.

It was working with `1.5.x of okhttp version`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What does it means "it does not work"??? Does it fails at compile time or runtime? What kind of error does it shows?

Answer (score 0):

Code from documentation

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://kenumir.pl/")
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

Method **execute** is the key ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What does it means "it does not work"??? Does it fails at compile time or runtime? What kind of error does it shows? As of OkHttip 2.x.x, there's been a change in the way to open HttpUrlConnections, you need to include a new module and this should work:

```
// OkHttp 1.x:
HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(url);

// OkHttp 2.x:
HttpURLConnection connection = new OkUrlFactory(client).open(url);
```

see [OkHttp Release notes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more information .